# Unable to deploy Azure Function in Java onto Azure cloud

Tags: java, azure, maven, azure-functions

I have been trying to deploy an Azure function I developed in Java and built using Maven. But running the command `mvn azure-functions:deploy` does not work. Even though I have configured proxies on my system, it fails to get deployed and ends with the error below.

Some other points:

1. It's a free account
2. Commands like `mvn azure-functions:package` and `azure-functions:run` are successful

`Failed to execute goal com.microsoft.azure:azure-functions-maven-plugin:1.4.1:deploy (default-cli) on project satya: java.net.UnknownHostException: No such host is known (management.azure.com)`

I am not sure where I am going wrong.

**Updating with POM.XML**

4.0.0

```
<groupId>az.xz.as</groupId>
<artifactId>satya</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>Azure Java Functions</name>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <azure.functions.maven.plugin.version>1.4.1</azure.functions.maven.plugin.version>
    <azure.functions.java.library.version>1.3.1</azure.functions.java.library.version>
    <functionAppName>satya-29042020</functionAppName>
    <stagingDirectory>${project.build.directory}/azure-functions/${functionAppName}</stagingDirectory>
</properties>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>maven.snapshots</id>
        <name>Maven Central Snapshot Repository</name>
        <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>maven.snapshots</id>
        <name>Maven Central Snapshot Repository</name>
        <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.23.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.azure.functions</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-functions-java-library</artifactId>
            <version>${azure.functions.java.library.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.azure.functions</groupId>
        <artifactId>azure-functions-java-library</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
      <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
      <version>6.2.2.jre8</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Test -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
                <artifactId>azure-functions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${azure.functions.maven.plugin.version}</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>

    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-functions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <!-- function app name -->
                <appName>${functionAppName}</appName>
                <!-- function app resource group -->
                <resourceGroup>vfs_data_lake_demo</resourceGroup>
                <!-- function app service plan name -->
                <appServicePlanName>ASP-vfsdatalakedemo-b909</appServicePlanName>
                <!-- function app region-->
                <!-- refers https://github.com/microsoft/azure-maven-plugins/tree/develop/azure-functions-maven-plugin#supported-regions for all valid values -->
                <region>eastus2</region>
                <!-- function pricingTier, default to be consumption if not specified -->
                <!-- refers https://github.com/microsoft/azure-maven-plugins/tree/develop/azure-functions-maven-plugin#supported-pricing-tiers for all valid values -->
                <!-- <pricingTier></pricingTier> -->
                <runtime>
                    <!-- runtime os, could be windows, linux or docker-->
                    <os>windows</os>
                    <!-- for docker function, please set the following parameters -->
                    <!-- <image>[hub-user/]repo-name[:tag]</image> -->
                    <!-- <serverId></serverId> -->
                    <!-- <registryUrl></registryUrl>  -->
                </runtime>
                <appSettings>
                    <property>
                        <name>FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION</name>
                        <value>~3</value>
                    </property>                        
                </appSettings>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>package-functions</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>package</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-resources</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <overwrite>true</overwrite>
                        <outputDirectory>${stagingDirectory}</outputDirectory>
                        <resources>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>${project.basedir}</directory>
                                <includes>
                                    <include>host.json</include>
                                    <include>local.settings.json</include>
                                </includes>
                            </resource>
                        </resources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${stagingDirectory}/lib</outputDirectory>
                        <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                        <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
                        <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
                        <includeScope>runtime</includeScope>
                        <excludeArtifactIds>azure-functions-java-library</excludeArtifactIds>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <!--Remove obj folder generated by .NET SDK in maven clean-->
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <filesets>
                    <fileset>
                        <directory>obj</directory>
                    </fileset>
                </filesets>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: have you tried through zip deployment?

Comment: Can you show the pom.xml file of your function app?

Comment: @ThiagoCustodio: I am not sure about zip deployment. Should I create a function app first in azure portal?

Answer (score 0):

`mvn azure-functions:deploy` is mainly used for the first time a function is deployed, because it produces the necessary files. It will generate random resources, by design.

Take a look of this:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-first-java-maven?pivots=java-build-tools-maven#deploy-the-function-to-azure

Using `mvn azure-functions:deploy` should not cause a problem. Have you set something in pom.xml? There shouldn't be any `-` characters in the storage account name.

This is my pom.xml, and it has no issues:

4.0.0

```
<groupId>com.function</groupId>
<artifactId>ci-cd-demo</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>Azure Java Functions</name>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <azure.functions.maven.plugin.version>1.4.1</azure.functions.maven.plugin.version>
    <azure.functions.java.library.version>1.3.1</azure.functions.java.library.version>
    <functionAppName>ci-cd-demo-20200406102526581</functionAppName>
    <stagingDirectory>${project.build.directory}/azure-functions/${functionAppName}</stagingDirectory>
</properties>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>maven.snapshots</id>
        <name>Maven Central Snapshot Repository</name>
        <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>maven.snapshots</id>
        <name>Maven Central Snapshot Repository</name>
        <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.23.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.azure.functions</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-functions-java-library</artifactId>
            <version>${azure.functions.java.library.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.azure.functions</groupId>
        <artifactId>azure-functions-java-library</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Test -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
                <artifactId>azure-functions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${azure.functions.maven.plugin.version}</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>

    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-functions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <!-- function app name -->
                <appName>${functionAppName}</appName>
                <!-- function app resource group -->
                <resourceGroup>java-functions-group</resourceGroup>
                <!-- function app service plan name -->
                <appServicePlanName>java-functions-app-service-plan</appServicePlanName>
                <!-- function app region-->
                <!-- refers https://github.com/microsoft/azure-maven-plugins/tree/develop/azure-functions-maven-plugin#supported-regions for all valid values -->
                <region>westus</region>
                <!-- function pricingTier, default to be consumption if not specified -->
                <!-- refers https://github.com/microsoft/azure-maven-plugins/tree/develop/azure-functions-maven-plugin#supported-pricing-tiers for all valid values -->
                <!-- <pricingTier></pricingTier> -->
                <runtime>
                    <!-- runtime os, could be windows, linux or docker-->
                    <os>windows</os>
                    <!-- for docker function, please set the following parameters -->
                    <!-- <image>[hub-user/]repo-name[:tag]</image> -->
                    <!-- <serverId></serverId> -->
                    <!-- <registryUrl></registryUrl>  -->
                </runtime>
                <appSettings>
                    <property>
                        <name>FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION</name>
                        <value>~3</value>
                    </property>
                </appSettings>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>package-functions</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>package</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-resources</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <overwrite>true</overwrite>
                        <outputDirectory>${stagingDirectory}</outputDirectory>
                        <resources>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>${project.basedir}</directory>
                                <includes>
                                    <include>host.json</include>
                                    <include>local.settings.json</include>
                                </includes>
                            </resource>
                        </resources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${stagingDirectory}/lib</outputDirectory>
                        <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                        <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
                        <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
                        <includeScope>runtime</includeScope>
                        <excludeArtifactIds>azure-functions-java-library</excludeArtifactIds>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <!--Remove obj folder generated by .NET SDK in maven clean-->
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <filesets>
                    <fileset>
                        <directory>obj</directory>
                    </fileset>
                </filesets>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

In most cases, you should use `func azure functionapp publish <FunctionAppName>` to deploy function apps. First, create a FunctionApp on Azure, and then deploy to this App. Here are the docs:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local?tabs=windows%2Ccsharp%2Cbash#publish

By the way, have you set the same function name? If it still doesn't work, please post your pom.xml file.

Comment: The storage account has no '-' in it. But I am not sure if we are going to use a storage account in @HTTPTriger annotation. And yes this is the first time I am trying to deploy an azure function on to cloud. I believe it is supposed to create one if we do 'mvn azure-functions:deploy'.